# DOM GetElementByTagName

Tags: php, dom

I am attempting to collect all the H1 tags from a block of code.  I am attempting to use this within a class and im keep getting errors and im unsure if it is because of the insertion into the class or if im coding it wrong as i am new to DOM coding.

Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByTagName()  This error refers to:

```
$head1 = $this->doc->getElementByTagName('H1');
```

File calling the class

```
<?php
include('../includes/configuration.php');
include('../functions/class.php');

$reports=new Functions();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_urls LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());  
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    $recc = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $id=$recc['id'];
    $content=$recc['content'];  

    $reports->content=$content;

    $test=$reports->collectHeadings();
    print_r($test);
}
?>
```

Class File

```
class Functions{
var $content;
var $doc;

public function collectHeadings(){
    $this->loadContent();
    $head1 = $this->doc->getElementByTagName('H1');
    return $head1;
}

public function loadContent(){
    $this->doc = new DOMDocument();
    $this->doc->loadHTML($this->content);
}
}
```

Comment: Am I lost here but getElementsByTagName, isnt that a javascript function? (Not php)(with a s)???

Comment: There is a DOMDocument class in php, which supports many of the XML selection and manipulation methods that the DOM accessible to javascript implements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it turns out you spelt it getElementByTagName, whereas the method is actually getElementsByTagName.

Comment: I thought so too, but OP is doing that inside `collectHeadings`

Comment: right you are. i'll see if i can figure anything else out and edit, otherwise will delete. thanks.

Comment: I am sort of new here, is it good practice to leave the incorrect part in your answer when you edit it (for posterity)? Or should I completely replace it?

Comment: :-) right you are about the typo. Doesn't matter editing it. In fact it is better to edit it, if you want to completely rewrite your answer (as is this case), so that you do not confuse those who read it..

Comment: Thank You.  I need to get to sleep.